# Get ssrs report's parameter list from report viewer instead of web service call

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm rendering server reports (remote processing mode) through the ReportViewer control, but I also need to save the list of parameters each report has. The ReportViewer automatically generate the parameter-prompts for each report it's rendering, so I'm wondering if there's an event or properties that could allow me to access these parameter-prompts to obtain the name and number of parameters of the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via call to "SetParameters" method. Here's a sample code (VB.NET):

```
Dim aParamList As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)

aParamList.Add(New ReportParameter("ParamName1", "Parameter Value 1"))
aParamList.Add(New ReportParameter("ParamName2", "Parameter Value 2"))

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(aParamList)
```

If you don't know parameter names, to get them from the report you can use "GetParameters" method:

```
For Each oParamInfo In  ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters
    'oParamInfo.Name would hold parameter name
Next
```